# express error Cannot GET / when I move the router to challengeRouter file?

Tags: node.js, express, router

I have created expressjs API when I move the router to challengeRouter I have error message

> Cannot GET /

challengeRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');

function routes() {
    const challengeRouter = express.Router();
    challengeRouter.route("/challenge")
    .get((req, res) => {

        const respons = { hello: `this is get ${sealingNumber}`  };
        res.json(respons);
    });

    return challengeRouter;

  }
  
  module.exports = routes;
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const challengeRouter = require('./routes/challengeRouter');

app.use("/api",challengeRouter)


app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

Comment: To get access to the routes with the way you have it, I think you need to do `app.use("/api",challengeRouter())`. When you do something like, `app.use("/api",challengeRouter)` express is expecting to send `(req, res)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining all end points in a single file is a fine way to get started, but that won’t scale well as you add more routes to the app.

```
const router = new express.Router()
router.post('/someEndpoint', (req, res) => {
// Do something
})
module.exports = router
```

The router defined in the file above can be added into the Express application in index.js

```
app.use(router)
```

For more https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html